# Get text before delimiter

Tags: jquery

I have this checkbox value: `10/07-08/24_NOV`, and I have this code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() { 
    var tot = 100;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        tot -= parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#outputDiv').html(tot)
});
});
```

I need jQuery to give me only the first value before the first delimiter, number 10.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**split()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to get the value before first `/` ,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D8fYf/)**

```
$(this).val().split('/')[0]
```